# calling input from other files other than ui and server

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to call input function from other files other than ui and server in shiny
Example,
I have below code in ui.R

```
selectinput("id","name", choice = c(......))
```

Usually we call `input$id` in server.R file . But is there a way to call this from another .R file. Example "functions.R" is the file where i have written all my functions, in one place i need to call `input$id`, but getting error like `object 'input' not found`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

In general, you can place some of your server code in a file "functions.R" and then call `source("functions.R")` at the beginning of your server function. This will load the code and create an instance of the functions in your memory. Just having them in "functions.R"  is not enough for R to be able to execute them.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    source("functions.R")
    # Additional server-side code
}
```